# Border Shaping and Styling in CSS

Tags: css, border

I want to envelop my div in borders that look somewhat like this:
http://na.leagueoflegends.com/ ,
but I'm wondering what's the right approach to make this. 
Is it just a border with images or is it something more complicated to get that border shape?

Comment: Use your browser's tools. Inspect the element.

Answer (score -1):

You can create any shape of your div using CSS3 and then apply borders to it. Have a look at 
https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: If you are not able to create your required shape, upload exact image of your shape and CSS code which you have tried, so that we can help you out with your CSS.